# Flutter countdown timer using Duration

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a function inside `initState()` that compares current time and saved time in database and stores the difference in a variable called `nextTime`

This is my initState:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
    getOffsetSign();
    setState(() {
      nextTime = nextAlarmTime(); // nextAlarmTime is the function that returns the difference in duration
      print("From inside init state: $nextTime");
    });
    countDownTimer(nextTime);
  }
```

I need some function that'll trigger when user visits the home page

This is what I've done till now:

```
  Timer? timer;

  void countDownTimer(Duration duration) {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) => setState(() {
        if (duration.inSeconds == 0) {
          timer.cancel();
        }
      }),
    );
  }
```

Problem: The timer only updates when the page is visited. It does not count down on it's own.

Comment: You don't need to use 'setState' inside 'initState'.

Comment: You need to use 'setState' inside 'countDownTimer' for 'timer'.

Comment: `
  void countDownTimer(Duration duration) {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) => setState(() {
        if (duration.inSeconds == 0) {
          setState(() {
            timer.cancel();
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            duration - oneSec;
          });
        }
      }),
    );
  }
`

Is this what you're talking about? It's not workinh

Comment: 'setState' should wrap 'timer = ...'.

Comment: Right now, I'm writing from mobile. So, I could not write total of the code.

Comment: @Akif alright I'll keep on trying but please do share when you're in PC

Answer (score 0):

> I need some function that'll trigger when user visits the home page

Try to store the nextAlarmTime in DB / shared preferences, then compare it when user visit home page again.

Comment: That was not my question. My countdowntimer was not couting down on it's own. I had to visit the page every time to get the  counter